# Склонение существительных после дробных числительных

Tags: склонение

Как правильно: в течение 3,5 часов или 3,5 часа?

Comment: в научной статье - и если точнее - то в течение первых 3,5 часов или 3,5 часа??

Comment: См. правила русского языка п. 8 по ссылке http://evartist.narod.ru/text1/59.htm

Comment: pyshka, Вы что-нибудь слышали о таком понятии, как знаки препинания? Пока я Вам их не расставила, у Вас не было ни одного.

Answer (score 3):

Второе: в течение 3,5 часа  - в течение трёх целых,пяти десятых часа

Возможно : в течение 3,5 часов- в течение трёх с половиной часов, но это если бы было словами.

Comment: это в статье...не могу читать 3,5 часа - режет глаз!!!

Comment: Если цифрой - " пять десятых частей часа"

Comment: вот уточняю - первых 3,5 часов или часа??

Comment: http://rusoved.ru/pravila/28.html  : существительное, обозначающее количество, при дробном числительном ставится в родительном падеже: от семи восьмых (квадрата), к двадцати семидесятым (площади). В течении первых трёх целых пяти десятых часа.(Пяти десятых частей чего?-часа)